# EF6 linq to sql The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have to System.Timers.Timer in my application. The intervals of those timers are 1000 and 120000. And each time they tick, they save some entity to database.

But sometimes i get this error in my code; The context cannot be used while the model is being created.This exception may be thrown if the context is used inside the OnModelCreating method or if the same context instance is accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Note that instance members of DbContext and related classes are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This is my code:

```
            using ACTMULTILib;
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Diagnostics;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;

            namespace RenderingPlcScanner
            {
                class Program
                {
                    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
                    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
                    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
                    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
                    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
                    const int SW_SHOW = 5;
                    private System.Timers.Timer timer1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    private System.Timers.Timer timer2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
                    private GEOTEKRENDERINGEntities grEntities = new GEOTEKRENDERINGEntities();
                    private ActEasyIF plc = new ActEasyIF();
                    private bool isUpToDate = true;
                    private StreamWriter writer;
                    public Program()
                    {
                        grEntities.Database.Connection.Open();

                        timer1.Interval = 1000;
                        timer1.Elapsed += timer1_Elapsed;
                        timer2.Interval = 120000;
                        timer2.Elapsed += timer2_Elapsed;
....                        
                        if (plc.Open() == 0)
                        {
                            timer1.Start();
                            timer2.Start();
                        }
....
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    void timer2_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
                    {
        .....
        .....

                        tblSicakSu tSicakSu = new tblSicakSu();
                        tSicakSu.Seviye = Math.Truncate(seviye * 100) / 100;
                        tSicakSu.Sicaklik = Math.Truncate(sicaklik * 100) / 100;
                        tSicakSu.Tuketim = tuketim[0];
                        tSicakSu.Zaman = DateTime.Now;
                        grEntities.tblSicakSu.Add(tSicakSu);
                        grEntities.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    void timer1_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
                    {
                        timer1.Stop();
                        try
                        {
        ......


                            DateTime amin = now.AddMinutes(1);
                            short[] set = new short[3];
                            plc.ReadDeviceBlock2("D5010", 3, out set[0]);
                            //Console.WriteLine(amin.ToString() + " - " + set[0] + "/" + set[1]);
                            if (amin.Hour == set[0] && amin.Minute == set[1] && !tuketimAlindi)
                            {
                                tuketimAlindi = true;
                                short[] tuketim = new short[5];
                                plc.ReadDeviceBlock2("D3013", 5, out tuketim[0]);
                                tblTuketim tTuketim = new tblTuketim();
                                tTuketim.Zaman = DateTime.Now;
                                tTuketim.YumusakSu = tuketim[0];
                                tTuketim.DonusSu = tuketim[2];
                                tTuketim.SicakSu = tuketim[4];
                                grEntities.tblTuketim.Add(tTuketim);
                                grEntities.SaveChanges();
                                //Console.WriteLine("Tüketim alındı");
                            }
                            else if (amin.Minute != set[1])
                            {
                                tuketimAlindi = false;
                            }

                            short[] data = new short[1];
                            plc.ReadDeviceBlock2("D4300", 1, out data[0]);
                            if (data[0] == 0)
                            {
                                short[] sayac = new short[1];
                                plc.ReadDeviceBlock2("D14000", 1, out sayac[0]);
                                //Console.WriteLine(sayac[0]);
                                if (sayac[0] > 0)
                                {
                                    short[] datablock = new short[10];
                                    plc.ReadDeviceBlock2("D15000", 10, out datablock[0]);
                                    short uretimID = datablock[0];
                                    short kazanNo = datablock[1];
                                    short malzeme_kodu = datablock[2];
                                    short malzeme_miktari = datablock[3];
                                    short yil = datablock[4];
                                    short ay = datablock[5];
                                    short gun = datablock[6];
                                    short saat = datablock[7];
                                    short dakika = datablock[8];
                                    short saniye = datablock[9];
                                    var vUretim = (from uretim in grEntities.tblUretim where uretim.PartiNo == uretimID select uretim).ToList();
                                    if (vUretim.Count == 0)
                                    {
                                        tblUretim tUretim = new tblUretim();
                                        tUretim.PartiNo = uretimID;
                                        tUretim.KazanNo = kazanNo;
    ....
        ......

                                        grEntities.tblUretim.Add(tUretim);
                                        grEntities.SaveChanges();
                                        short[] value = new short[1];
                                        value[0] = 1;
                                        plc.WriteDeviceBlock2("D4300", 1, ref value[0]);
                                    }
                                    else if (vUretim.Count == 1)
                                    {
                                        tblUretim tUretim = vUretim[0];                     
    ....    
                                             short[] partiTavukUnuMiktari = new short[1];
            .....
                                        grEntities.SaveChanges();
                                        short[] value = new short[1];
                                        value[0] = 1;
                                        plc.WriteDeviceBlock2("D4300", 1, ref value[0]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            writer.WriteLine("----------------------------------Error (" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ") ---------------------------------------------------");
                            writer.WriteLine(ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace);
                            writer.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                            writer.Flush();
                            //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
                        }
                        timer1.Start();
                    }

                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        new Program();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is a huge load of code. Please post a small yet complete reproduce of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the timers are causing multiple threads to access the same instance of your context class, and when the second thread tries to use the class, it is busy still trying to create the model.

You have a couple of options to rectify. The simplest, I think, would be to disable the second timer when the app or form loads, and enable it only after the first iteration of the first timer's code has run.

Alternately, you can have each timer use its own instance of the context.

Or you could catch the exception and exit the method, and wait until the next time around to use the context object.